# How to add some more constraints with geoNear

Tags: node.js, mongodb, geolocation, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is my mongoose schema -

```
var userDestinationSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    uid: String,                
    update_time: Date,          
    some_data: String,

    location:{                  //<INDEXED as 2d>
        lon: Number,
        lat: Number
    }
});



var userDestinationModel = mongoose.model('userDestinationModel', userDestinationSchema);
```

To query the model for geoNear, I doing this.

```
userDestinationModel.geoNear(lng, lat, { maxDistance : 1.5 }, 
              function(err, results, stats) {
                   console.log(results);
                });
```

**How to add some more constraints, like a particular value of some_data?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "best way" is to use the [**`$near`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) operator or [**`$nearSphere`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/) as required. The [`.geoNear()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.geoNear) method of mongoose uses the older [`geoNear` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/command/geoNear/) of MongoDB. The other operators play better with other query operators in recent versions:

```
userDestinationModel.find({ 
    "location": {
        "$near": [ lng, lat ],
        "$maxDistance": 1.5
    },
    "update_time": { "$gt": new Date("2015-01-01") }
},function(err,result) {

});
```

You can also use the aggregation framework form of [$geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/). This has it's own "query" option to specify additional information:

```
userDestinationModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$geoNear": {
            "near": [ lng, lat ],
            "maxDistance": 1.5,
            "distanceField": "distance",
            "query": {
                "update_time": { "$gt": new Date("2015-01-01") }
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,result) {

    }
);
```

And that allows other options as well as being much like the ["command form"](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/command/geoNear/) where it projects and additional "distanceField" in the results that you could possibly use for later sorting or filtering or whatever.

You should also be able to specify "query" as an option to the mongoose method:

```
userDestinationModel.geoNear(lng, lat, 
    { 
        "maxDistance" : 1.5, 
        "query": { 
            "update_time": { "$gt": new Date("2015-01-01") } 
        } 
    }, 
    function(err, results, stats) {
        console.log(results);
    });
```

But as a personal preference I would go for the newer operators unless you have a dependency on older server version support.

Also try to move away from legacy co-ordinate pairs and to GeoJSON, as it is much more consistent with other API's you will likely work with in data exchange as well as supporting the wider variety of GeoJSON types. Be aware if moving to GeoJSON that parameters like "maxDistance" and the distance returned are measure in "meters" and not "radians" as is the case with legacy co-ordinates.